# Collision detection not working with my brick breaker program?

Tags: java

My program has been experiencing an odd bug i just cannot seem to fix. In summary, whenever I switch two if statements, only the one coming afte tthe first one will work.

Example: (The ball will successfully collide with the top, but won't with the bottom.)

```
public void update()
{
    if(enemies != null)
    {
        for(Enemy e : enemies)
            if(c.getBall().getHitbox().intersects(e.getHitbox()))
            {

                if(e.collidedBottom())
                    c.getBall().setSpeedY((c.getBall().ballSpeed));
                if(e.collidedTop())
                    c.getBall().setSpeedY(-(c.getBall().ballSpeed));

                deadEnemies.add(e);
            }

        enemies.removeAll(deadEnemies);
    }
```

Now if i switched the positions of the two if statements like so;

```
if(e.collidedTop())
    c.getBall().setSpeedY(-(c.getBall().ballSpeed));
if(e.collidedBottom())
    c.getBall().setSpeedY((c.getBall().ballSpeed));
```

The ball will successfully react the way it should when colliding with the bottom, but not with the top. Here is the two collision methods:

```
public boolean collidedBottom()
{ 
    if(c.getBall().getBallY() <= enemy.y + enemy.height && 
        c.getBall().getBallX() + c.getBall().getHitbox().width >= enemy.x
            && c.getBall().getBallX() <= enemy.x + enemy.width)
        return true;

    return false;
}

public boolean collidedTop()
{ 
    if(c.getBall().getBallY() + c.getBall().getHitbox().height >= enemy.y && 
         c.getBall().getBallX() + c.getBall().getHitbox().width >= enemy.x
            && c.getBall().getBallX() <= enemy.x + enemy.width)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Enemy refers to the current focused block in the loop.

Comment: Look at the logic inside your collided* methods again. This looks suspiciously like a copy&paste error.

Comment: How about your update loop?.. in collision you need a buffer zone.. because at high speed on some frame you may have passed your checking point.

Comment: @3141 I have, thrice. It's just weird that switching the positions of 2 if statements makes one work and renders the other obsolete.

Comment: @Yan.F That's true, and that's why I used >= and <= just in case I missed the checking point in due to my update loop. Is there another way of getting around this though?

Comment: Don't you need to toggle the speed direction in both cases?

Comment: All those repeated getThis/getThat also suggest that having a `collidesWith` on either Ball or Hitbox might be worthwhile. It would also extract it for simpler isolation testing.

Comment: @3141 That's what I'm doing, no? The variable ballSpeed is set to 4, so if it hits the bottom it should be going down, therefore adding to the y coordinate, opposite for going up.